# Dual Booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, multi-boot

I'm planning on dual booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu on one of my old computers, when I was looking at disk management I have this:

[image]

My question is, if I install Ubuntu on the D: drive, will it work properly or would I get errors? I haven't done a dual boot in years and never had something like this before. Thanks for the answers in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you are going to have problems with that partition scheme.
Just remember that your data stored there will be deleted, so do a backup.
Also, during Ubuntu installation, you can format that partition in Ext4 instead of NTFS, which is better for linux use, and add another small partition to use as swap.

Answer (score 0):

It should work out fine. Key word being "should", Linux is incredibly finicky at times.

I've done dual-boot situations similar to yours and the install went off without a hitch. The drivers, on the other hand, were a completely different story.